# SwiftUI wrapping UIViewController using UIViewControllerRepresentable

Tags: swiftui, uitextfield, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I have question about wrapping custom UIViewControllers into SwiftUI view using UIViewControllerRepresentable. Does anyone have issue with UITextFields in such case?
I have situation that sometimes this textfield works normally when wrapped and otherwise they just work for a while and stopped working after editinig text for about 10sec or hiding/showing keyboard, or they doesn't work at all.
Situation seems to be very odd.

Comment: No, add your code.

Comment: It is too many code that can cause this issue it happans randomly both then i present viewcontrollers from root or when i wrap it into uiviewcontroller representable. Some screens works ok other just dosen't work, yet another work for a while and stopped working on second keyboard appearance. Very odd situation. I think I will need to investigate it myself as pasting entire app here is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Ok it was the problem with

```
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool { true }
```

on `UIViewController`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621130-canbecomefirstresponder